# Where to put the MockK settings.properties file in an Android project?

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockk

We're using MockK for unit testing our Android project. Since we're almost always use `mockk(relayed=true)` we wanted to set it as default in the `settings.properties` as [suggested in the docs](https://github.com/mockk/mockk#settings-file).

It says: 
"create io/mockk/settings.properties file in resources."

Ok, so I thought it would be a good idea to put it here: `src/main/res/io/mockk/settings.properties`. Unfortunately, it does not work. If I remove the explicit `relaxed=true` in the individual mocks all the tests fail.

So, where do I actually place the settings file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an Android project, the file must go into:
`app/src/test/resources/io/mockk/settings.properties`

It must be `resources` not just `res`.